# What determines System Information's Kind attribute?

Tags: system-information, apple-silicon

Some Apple Silicon applications are showing up in the System Information column **Kind** as **iOS**, but in the Application Info, the **Kind** is **Application (Apple Silicon)**. Other applications do say **Apple Silicon** in System Information.

I am curious, if anyone knows the magic to make the **Kind** appear as **Apple Silicon** versus **iOS**?

[image: Kind iOS applications]

[image: Zoom is kind Apple Silicon]

[image: VSCode insiders identifies as Apple Silicon in app info]

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428037/from-system-profile-what-does-kind-mean however no answer