# Why is Spotify marked 'iOS' under the 'Kind' column in System Information?

Tags: macos, applications, spotify

It's the only one marked iOS, and I'm not sure what that means in the context of an M1 MacOS system.
[image]

Comment: A screenshot might help to allow us to see what you see.

Comment: Anyway, how did you install Spotify on your Mac?

Comment: I added a pic. VLC seems to be another example after I updated to the native Apple version. But I'm not sure how that's different the "Apple Silicon" listing.

Comment: I migrated spotify from my intel MB with Time machine, then Spotify updated itself on the M1 machine.

Comment: Looking at my Applications I see VisualStudio and Emacs are iOS - and that does not run on iOS. I suspect that these are non Universal apps - but how macOS shows Apple Silicon or IOS is the question - which I have asked before https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428037/from-system-profile-what-does-kind-mean but no answer

Comment: Apps from the iPad/iPhone store are iOS which makes sense but iOS. Other seems include the apps written in an interpreter e.g. python and Java based but includes others

Comment: I see exactly the same, both VLC and Spotify showing up as iOS on an M2 mac. According to this (link below), some iOS apps are capable of running on OSX.. though I definitely never obtained either from the Mac app store..   

https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/app-store/fird2c7092da/mac